# Menu Bar Not Displaying Properly on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, menu, display

Below is the code I'm using to build a website. Everything looks great on every web browser except for Safari. The website is in both Japanese and English, and for whatever reason, the gray line underneath the menu bar isn't displaying properly on the Japanese version of the website when I test it in Safari. The English version works fine in Safari. I'd like it so that the gray line that's on the bottom of the menu bar is displayed as normal.

I've tried changing the height to 100vx, but that didn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:morikoboshi.com' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }

 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
} 

if(!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
    window.location.reload();
}
```

```css
.searchbar{float: right;}

 .image{text-align: center;}

 .setsumei{margin-left: 20px;
           margin-right: 20px;}

 .footer{width: 100%; 
           height: 40px; 
           text-align: center;
           border-top: 1px solid black; 
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;
           padding: 10px;}

 .page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -40px; 
}

 .page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; 
  }

 .site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 10px; 
}

 .site-footer {
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}



 @media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) {
 .responsive-image-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
      }
    img{width:85%;}
    }


 *, *:before, *:after {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}    

 ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

 .cp_cont {
    height: auto;
}

/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
            transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
 .cp_offcm03 nav,
 .cp_offcm03 ul {
    height: 100%;
}

 .cp_offcm03 li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a {
    display: block;    
    padding: 15px 45px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
            transition: background-color .3s ease-in;
}

 .cp_offcm03 a:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* menu toggle */
 #cp_toggle03 {
    display: none;
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
                    transform: translateX(0);
}

 .cp_mobilebar {
    display: none;

}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    padding: 35px auto;
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
            transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}   

 .cp_content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 65vh;
    text-align: center;

}

@media (max-width: 1130px)and (min-width: 280px) {
/* menu */
 .cp_offcm03 {
        position: fixed;
        left: -250px;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

 .cp_offcm03 nav {
        background: white;
        border-right: 0.5px solid lightgray;
        margin-left: -210px;
    }



 .cp_offcm03 li {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 0;}



 .cp_offcm03 a {
        padding: 20px;

    }

/* menu toggle */
 .cp_mobilebar {
        display: block;
        z-index: 2000;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;


    }

 .cp_menuicon {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55%;
        margin-top: -0.3em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0.2em;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease;
                transition: transform .3s ease;
    }
 .cp_menuicon > span:before,
 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        -webkit-transition: transform .3s ease-in;
                transition: transform .3s ease-in;
    }

 .cp_menuicon > span:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.6em);
                transform: translateY(-0.6em);
    }

 .cp_menuicon > span:after {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0.6em);
                transform: translateY(0.6em);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar .cp_menuicon { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                transform: rotate(45deg);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:before,
 #cp_toggle03:checked + .cp_mobilebar span:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_offcm03 {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
    }

 #cp_toggle03:checked ~ .cp_container {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
                transform: translateX(250px);
    }

 input:checked ~ #h-menu_black {
    display: block;/*カバーを表示*/
    opacity: .6;
}

 #h-menu_black {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
}

/* content */
 .cp_container {
        top: 60px;
        height: 92vh;
        text-align: center; 
    } 

 .noscroll{
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ja">
        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" charset="utf-8">
        
    <body style="background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif;">
        
    <title>MORIKOBOSHI・ホームページ</title>
          
    <div class="page-wrap">
         
    <div class="cp_cont">
    <input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
    <div class="cp_mobilebar">
    <label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
    <span></span>
    </label>
    </div>
    <label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
    <div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
            
    <header class="cp_offcm03">
            
    <nav>
    <ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
                
    <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Website_Home_Page.html">ホーム</a></li>
    <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Website_Blog.html">ブログ</a></li>
    <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Website_About.html">このサイトについて</a></li>
    <li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="Bibliography.html">参考文献</a></li>
        
    <div class="searchbar"> 
                
    <form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; position: inline;">
    <input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Googleカスタム検索" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;">
    <input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="検索" style="padding-left: 5px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 34px; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center;">
    <input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html">    
        
        
    
     
    </form>
    </div> 
    </ul>    
    </nav>
    </header> 
        
    <br><div class="image" style="margin: 10px;">
        
    <a href="Website_JapanTravel.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Travel/Homepage_Travel_Japanese.jpg" alt="Travel" width="85%"></a>
        
    <div class=" responsive-image-container"><a href="photos/Blog/Japanese_Culture/Blog/yokai/yokai.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Yokai/Homepage_yokai_Japanese.jpg" alt="Yokai" width="42.4%"></a> <a href="photos/Links/Kansai/Kansai_html_photos/Kyoto_html_photo/Kyoto/Blog/Kongoji/Kongoji_html_photo/Kongoji.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Kongoji/Kongoji_homepage_Japanese.jpg" alt="Kongoji" width="42.4%"></a>
    </div>
        
    <div class=" responsive-image-container"><a href="photos/Links/Kanto/Kanto_html_photos/Saitama_html_photos/Saitama/Blog/Tamagawa_Onsen/Tamagawa_Onsen_html_photo/Tamagawa_Onsen.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/Tamagawa_Onsen/Homepage_Tamagawa_Onsen_Japanese.jpg" alt="Tamagawa_Onsen" width="42.4%"></a> <a href="Website_About.html"><img src="photos/Home_Page/About_Website/Homepage_Website_Japanese.jpg" alt="Koizumi" width="42.4%"></a>
    </div>
        
    <br><br><footer class="site-footer" style="font-size: 12px;">MORIKOBOSHI© | <a href="Website_Home_Page_English.html">English</a></footer></div>
          
    </div>
          
    
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add a relevant and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is based upon my coding?